# Difference between dd-mm-yyyy and dd-mmm-yyyy

Tags: date, datetime, date-formatting, culture

Is it ok to use `dd-mm-yyyy` or `dd-mmm-yyyy` for UK. I used `dd-mmm-yyyy` format in my web application for UK.

```
Select  CONVERT(varchar(11),ArrivalDate,106)
```

But the `PM` asked me,

> Are you sure that this is the correct date format for UK ?

I searched on [Web](https://www.google.com.pk/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=m5uZV-X9LoG2a8-0qYAM#safe=active&q=date%20format%20uk) but find `dd-mm-yyyy` and nothing about `dd-mmm-yyyy` for UK. 
Can you please tell me whether they both are two different formats for different countries or its just display style and could be used for a country like UK ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: It's too bad we can't get the world to standardize on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which is yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is only Display style.

- `mm` is the number of the month (1..12) and
- `mmm` is the short Name of the month (jan, ... dec)

Comment: Careful, by the IETF standard, it's case sensitive. therefore "jan" and "dec" aren't accepted dissplay value for `mmm`; it would be "Jan" and "Dec".

https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1

Answer (score 7):

Basically, `mm` shows the month as as a **two-digit** integer where *01 equals to January* ... *12 equals to December*.

`mmm` on the other hand, will show the **three-letter** abbreviation of the month, respectively: *Jan, Feb, Mar* ... *Dec*.

`dd-mm-yyyy`: '30-05-2016'

`dd-mmm-yyyy`: '30-May-2016'

Answer (score 1):

You can use both, just depending on your preference of how the month part is displayed: as number or as text (like `28-07-2016` or `28-Jul-2016`).

With the last option, users from other regions will not have any doubt about a date like April 3rd, because it is shown as `03-Apr-2017`, whilest the first option will display it as `03-04-2017` which on other regionales (en-us for example) stands for March 4th.

Answer (score 1):

Like everywhere else in the world there are different standards for date format. You will at least find definitions for short dates and long dates format for each country. For instance in the U.K. the following are all valid:

- 6 Sept
- 6 September
- 6 September 2019
- 6th September 2019
- the 6th of September 2019
- the 6th of September, 2019
- 6/9/19, 6.9.19, or 6-9-19
- 06/09/2019, 06.09.2019, or 06-09-2019
- 6Sept2019, or 6-Sept-19

The first one in this list would be expressed as: `d-mmm`.

The [IETF (via RFC 7231)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1) regulates this standard and what `mmm` refers to for **date** formats. It's basically a "short name" for the month. Pay attention, by this standard, it's case sensitive.

Eventhough it's regulated, `mmm` can be confusing because in **date & time** formats it refers to milliseconds. (as per ISO 8601)

Answer (score 0):

dd-mm-yyyy requires values from 01 to 12 corresponding to month. dd-mmm-yyyy needs, Any month other than May to have a truncated value, Like for June you have to Jun.